# Why it shows Error while giving adt plugin in Eclipse for Android application development?

Tags: plugins, eclipse

I tried a lot to make available SDK to Eclipse by giving ADT plugin for android applicationdevelopment, but while installing it shows something like

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer
>   20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group
>   20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)   Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group
>   20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found.

Any help what I need to do please ?

Answer (score 1):

You need Eclipse Helios (3.6.2) & above for ADT v20+

> ADT 20.0.3 (August 2012)
>
> Dependencies:
>
> - Java 1.6 or higher is required for ADT 20.0.3.
> - Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 20.0.3.
> - ADT 20.0.3 is designed for use with SDK Tools r20.0.3.
>
> If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r20.0.3 into your SDK, use
>   the Android SDK Manager to do so.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html